# Is 涼台 not used anymore and does it differ from 陽台？

Tags: difference

In Chinese literature there are four poems:

```
春林花多媚，春鳥意多哀；春風復多情，吹我羅裳開。 
朝登涼台上，夕宿蘭池裡。乘風采芙蓉，夜夜得蓮子。 
自從別歡來，何日不相思？常恐秋葉零，無復連條時。 
淵冰厚三尺，素雪覆千里。我心如松柏，君情復何似？
```

As you can see, the word 涼台 occurs. I used to live in a very hot country, so the idea of 涼台 seems much more natural than 陽台。But lately native speakers from both China and Taiwan tell me to use 陽台. Is 涼台 limited to ancient Chinese, or does it carry a different meaning?

Comment: bkrs:涼台
1) 供乘凉用的平台。
2) 阳台。
balcony; veranda synonyms:相关: 阳台, 平台,(no indication of being out-of-date 过时), however jukuu only has 1 irrelevant (characters separated by other characters) example for 涼台 but 100 for 阳台 (all relevant, no other characters  between the 2 characters)

Comment: Both 阳台 and 凉台 are common and natural. Some people use them with no difference. Generally, the balcony in the apartment is often called 阳台(but still some call it 凉台).  You name it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both 陽台 and 涼台 can be translated as 'veranda, balcony and deck'

I suppose 陽台 refers to a deck you can sit on to enjoy sunshine, and 涼台 is a deck you sit on for cooling down. Which means the location of this deck determines how you call it.

陽台 should locate in an area that is open and have access to plenty of sunshine. While 涼台 should locate in an area with shade. surrounded by tree, or near water.

陽台 is a more common term because most people live in cities don't have a backyard to build a deck for cooling, but most apartment buildings do have balconies.

Answer (score 1):

臺 has the meaning "a structure that is high and flat, one can look in all directions" (高而平﹒可供眺望四方的建築物)

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000002479

so, when reading "朝登涼臺上", i would make a mental image of "ascend a [lookout tower](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=lookout+tower&newwindow=1&c2coff=1&client=safari&rls=en&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx57zO-IPWAhXKEpQKHcRECtEQ_AUICigB&biw=1276&bih=693) in the morning, look around the 360° scenario, let the summer breeze dry my sweat"

well, nowadays, most people are familiar with 陽臺, or 露臺, which is part of a building (balcony, maybe veranda).

imo, these two are different from "涼臺".

last, may i ask, how do you choose particular poems from the 子夜四時歌?

Comment: Just from some old lecture notes, because I think that's where I first saw 涼台. Are they not normally grouped together?

Comment: yes, most of the books, maybe all, would group 20 春歌, 20 夏歌, 18 秋歌 and 17 冬歌 together. like this in 古樂苑: https://archive.org/stream/06070492.cn#page/n14/mode/2up so, your lecture notes is very interesting, and inspiring, imo :-)